# Вопрос про встраиваемые и статические функции

Tags: c++, c, функции

```
// A.h
#ifndef _A_H_
#define _A_H_
static void aStatic(int x);
inline void aInline() {
  aStatic(6);
}
#endif // _A_H_

// A.cpp
#include "A.h"
static void aStatic() {
  // some code
}

// main.cpp
#include "A.h"

int main()
{
  aInline();  // так можно делать?
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

1) Нужно ли в хидер файле объявлять статическую функцию?
2) Можно ли в **си** (если поведение с С++ отличается, напишите) вызывать статическую функцию из другого файла, с помощью inline функций?
3) Если есть предложения/замечания, скажите

Comment: плиз, слово header по русски произносится "хэдэр"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Не просто не нужно — этого нельзя делать. Ваш пример не соберётся просто потому, что `aStatic` имеет внутреннее связывание (из-за `static`), значит использовать её можно только в том модуле трансляции, в котором она определена (A.cpp) и больше нигде. Вы же поместили её в заголовок, давая ложную надежду на то, что использовать её можно. Что Вы и пытаетесь делать, используя `aStatic` в main.cpp.

2) Для C++ ответ — нет, по причинам изложенным в п.1. Если только она не определена в том же заголовке, что и `inline` функция. Для C этого тоже делать нельзя, по причинам явно указаным в 6.7.4p3:

> An inline definition of a function with external linkage shall not
>   contain a definition of a modifiable object with static or thread
>   storage duration, and **shall not contain a reference to an identifier
>   with internal linkage**

3) Есть одно замечание, Вы прежде чем задавать вопрос, попробуйте скомпилировать код.

---

Если нужно скрыть какие-то функции, тогда нужно полностью убрать скрываемые функции из интерфейса, т.е. из заголовочного файла. Ваш пример можно переписать так:

```
// A.h
#ifndef _A_H_
#define _A_H_

void aInline();
#endif // _A_H_

// A.cpp
#include "A.h"
static void aStatic(int x);

static void aStatic() {
  // some code
}

void aInline() {
  aStatic(6);
}
// main.cpp
#include "A.h"

int main()
{
  aInline();  // так можно делать?
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Не нужно думать о том, что будет 2 косвенных вызова, скорее всего их не будет. Т.е. при вызове `aInline` вероятнее всего будет только один ассемблерный `call`. В любом случае, вопросами оптимизации стоит озадачиваться лишь после того, как измерения показали потребность в оной.

Comment: как это нет ключевого слова inline. Я даже стандарт пошел посмотреть - не, все на месте

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, исправил! Нечего писать про язык, с которым не работаешь :)

Comment: то есть единственное решение это сделать обычную ф-цию **void aFunc() {aStatic(6);}**?

Comment: @KtoTo, решением является неиспользование статической функции. Либо же сокрытие вызова оной в модуле трансляции, в котором она определена.

Comment: @ixSci я забыл при реализации aStatic, добавить слово static. Сейчас исправил. Мне нужно скрыть ф-цию aStatic. Но создать открытые другие ф-ции которые состоят только из вызова aStatic, с разными параметрами. И вопрос, можно ли как то написать код, что бы не было двойного вызова ф-ции?(aFunc1() -> aStatic(1) -- двойной вызов)

Comment: к тому же сэкономить место в памяти прошивки если бы можно было сделать inline

Comment: @KtoTo, обновил ответ

Comment: @KtoTo, `inline` это всё, что угодно, но не экономия места. Как раз наоборот. Да и учтите, что компилятор может спокойно игнорировать `inline` в части встраивания.